# Programmatically/Automatically disable GPS when not used

Tags: android, gps

When Android apps ask for the GPS to be enabled, after the app is turned off, GPS is not automatically turned off.
I suspect this is not only the case on my Honor 10, but on most Android phones.
This is a privacy and a energy wasting concern.

Is there a way to disable GPS after the app has been closed? I only find old, outdated answers to that question, or that it's not possible.

Both apps that do this, as well as sample code would be fine with me.